# PHP : unexpected '$curl' (T_VARIABLE)?

Tags: php, curl

I'm not seeing what the problem is here.

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$curl' (T_VARIABLE)

```
$file = 'https://www.somesite.com/conversion.jpg?id=blahblah&name='.$xmlval['fname'].'&city='.$xmlval['city'].'&state='.$xmlval['regionDisplay'].'&email='.$xmlval['email'].'&message='.($xmlval['rebill'] == 'true' ? 'Renewed ' : 'Purchased ').$spc_licenses.($spc_licenses == 1 ? ' license ' : ' licenses ').' of product!';

if (function_exists('curl_version')) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $file);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $content = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
}
else if (file_get_contents(__FILE__) && ini_get('allow_url_fopen'))
{
    $content = file_get_contents($file);
}
else
{
    echo 'error';  /* neither available */
}
```

Comment: which line you get this error, I cannot see any problem with your code.

Comment: Ponting to `$curl = curl_init();`

Comment: That error generally indicates a missing semicolon or bracket somewhere in your code. Have you checked the rest of your code?

Answer (score 0):

your code is fine, but check one in `phpini` that your curl is enabled or not `extension=php_curl.dll` this is the enabled state and `;extension=php_curl.dll` is the disabled state.

Comment: I'm using curl on the same domain in other scripts so I don't believe that is the issue.